# Book cover fonts

Tags: fonts, book-design, sans-serif, covers

I am typesetting my first book.  I am using Computer Modern for the font.  I am trying to decide which font to use for the covers/dust jacket.

I took a look at a number of similarly formatted books, and they all seem to use sans serif fonts for the cover, even if they are typeset with serif fonts in the body.  **Is there a good reason—aesthetic or otherwise—why one should use a sans serif font (*e.g.*, CMSS) over regular CMR for the cover?**

**Backstory:** My university has, in my opinion, an incredibly ugly format that is *required* for all Masters and Ph.D. theses.  Double spaced, single sided, letter paper, small margins, single column ... it just looks terrible.  For my Ph.D. dissertation I of course used the required formatting for the archival versions that go to the university library, however, I also created my own style file that I think looks a lot better.  I am going to use my "prettier" format for printing copies of my dissertation for my advisors, friends, family, *&c.*  The book binder I am using allows me to customize the cover of the book.

**Disclaimer:** I realize this question isn't specifically related to (La)TeX, however, it is realted to typesetting; I hope it is not off topic!

Comment: Typesetting and book design questions are on topic for this site. :)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the KOMA documentation puts it very nicely, when describing which title is created using `\maketitle` and how it differs from the book cover:

> A cover is actually something that should be created in a separate document. The cover often has a very individual format. It can also be designed with the help of a graphics or DTP program. A separate document should also be used because the cover will be printed on a different medium, possibly cardboard, and possibly with another printer.

This means: the layout/formatting of the main document has absolutely no bearing on the layout and formatting of the cover.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I had assumed.  The gist of my question, though, was whether or not certain fonts work better for the cover (regardless of which font is used for the main body).  I seem to recall reading some studies, for example, about the readability of certain fonts for signage.  That may be a bit too off topic for this forum, however.

Answer (score 4):

I wonder if your collection of books all come from a single source with a certain house style? It doesn't match my experience.

I current have 14 books sitting on my desk. Of those, 4 have sans serif typefaces for the printing on their covers, and 10 have serif typefaces on their covers.

I'm no expert, but I can't think of any reason why covers ought to use sans fonts; perhaps some people do it because it is one place where sans fonts do look appropriate, and they want some variety.

Computer Modern Roman doesn't seem like a great title font to me personally, but I think that's just a matter of taste. It's your book; if you like it, go for it.

Comment: On my desk right now I have Springer, Princeton U. Press, Prentice Hall, and Dover books; all use Sans on the cover and Serif in the body.